# Calculating sample size when you have 2 treatments and uneven distribution

Tags: experiment-design, sample-size, statistical-power, ab-test

I have 2 new conversion webpages to test. Leadership recommends 80% traffic to existing conversion webpage and 10% each to the 2 new conversion webpages (non-negotiable)

How do I calculate sample size? I understand the fundamentals of sample size calculation -  alpha, power, baseline conversion rate and minimum detectable effect needed but have done it for a 50/50 distribution and 1 treatment only..

I am unsure how to calculate for 2 treatment and uneven distribution. Can anyone guide me or refer me to a calculator or formula?

Comment: What null and alternative? What test statistic?

Answer (score 0):

Main point: use a standard RCT methodology but adjust your $\alpha$ level accordingly to account for multiple comparisons.

More details: Irrespective of how many arms we have and their respective sizes, it is still the case of the smaller sample sizes dominating the power of the study - smaller sample sizes inflate the occurrence of Type II errors. That means we need to run our experiment longer (to get more data) and/or make the different arms of the study have "more dramatic" changes (to get larger expected effect sizes). On top of that, we need to do a correction for multiple comparisons in our $\alpha$ too because we now have two comparisons, i.e. use a [family-wise error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate) for an adjusted level of $\frac{\alpha}{k}$ is usually fine ($k$=2 here). Notice that this latter point is counter to the usual idea of increasing $\alpha$ to avoid Type II errors. If one wants to explore this behaviour a bit further using  R, the function [`stats::p.adjust`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html) is immediately available in every R installation and offers a good place to start.